# working with BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, android-manifest

I used in my app uses-permission "BOOT_COMPLETED", but not working.
after reset phone, the app error "Unfortunately has stopped".
what is my problem?

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
           </category>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: post your stacktrace pleas.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed receiver start tag

```
 <receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver " >
```

And change your permission as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

i.e. Rewrite your manifest code as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver " >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

The permission line should be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

The declaration of your receiver should be (no category):

```
<receiver android:name="com.your.receiver.YourBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```